# Can "negative temperatures" be used for >100% efficiency engines?

Tags: energy, conservation-laws

An [article](https://www.livescience.com/25959-atoms-colder-than-absolute-zero.html) claims >100% efficiency engines possible using "negative temperatures":

> Negative temperatures could be used to create heat engines — engines that convert heat energy to mechanical work, such as combustion engines — that are more than 100-percent efficient, something seemingly impossible. Such engines would essentially not only absorb energy from hotter substances, but also colder ones. As such, the work the engine performed could be larger than the energy taken from the hotter substance alone.

What's the catch? I presume it's that the absolute energy required in order to attain negative temperatures in the first place would be far greater than that which we'd get from a process involving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The catch is that negative energies are metastable, not stable.  As they interact with other objects, their state collapses towards a stable state.

The beauty of such metastable systems is that they are not bound to follow the laws of thermodynamics as stable systems are.  The laws that are typically called the "laws of thermodynamics" apply to equilibrium systems.  Concepts like entropy are actually rather hard to define in the presence of meta stability.

As you've guessed, all real ways of creating negative temperatures require far more energy than they can produce as an engine.  As for whether they all *must* require more energy than they produce, that is actually an open question.  If the universe has an equilibrium state, entropy will inexorably guide the whole system towards that point.  Most mainstream physics does assume this process will occur.  However, it cannot be proven that this is the case. Consider a topology where time is circular (an Oroboros world).  There could exist a device which actually operates reversibly but appears, to us, to be a source of free energy (because we can't prove otherwise).  At the end of the universe, the device reverses itself, recreating the universe, and undoing all the "free energy" it provided.  This would make the entire universe a metastable oscillating system.

The mathematics is possible, though mainstream physics does not consider it to have a high likelihood of being true.  In our experience, everything moves towards an equilibrium state, driven by entropy.  Negative temperatures are a real thing.  We can make them, and they act really weird.  Claiming a particular engine using negative energy is one of these Oroboros devices would indeed qualify as quackery and require a preponderance of evidence before it would be accepted by the mainstream.

Comment: Thanks for the informative response. A follow-up: "As for whether they all must require more energy than they produce" - wouldn't the Law of Conservation of Mass-Energy be violated otherwise? Unless we begin with metastable states - we must engineer them, which will require a lot of energy. Are we aware of a method of harnessing more energy out of a closed system than we invest in it (even theoretically)? Closed as in - remaining in our universe, and not relying on black/white holes.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon You hit the nail on the head.  To play unlimited-energy games with metastable states, they have to have always existed.  If you create them, you have to engineer them using the tools you have available, and all of our tools that are available obey the laws of Convervation of mass/energy.  There is no known way around this, though when you start pondering "Is the entire universe a metastable system," you can start to drift outside the lines a bit because the scientific process itself starts to get challenged.

Comment: I would consider Asimov's [The Last Question](http://multivax.com/last_question.html) an excellent example of a potential universe that has such a metastable nature.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on a peer-reviewed article, in Science [1]. The system they study are cold atoms in a deep optical lattice. As the introduction of the paper reminds the reader,

> […] at positive temperatures a lower bound in energy is required, as the probabilities $P_i$ [the probability of occupation of a state of energy $E_i$: $P_i \propto e^{-E_i/k_B T}$, note of mine] would diverge for $E_i \to +\infty$. Negative temperatures, on the other hand, demand an upper bound in energy (1, 2). In daily life, negative temperatures are absent, because kinetic energy in most systems, including particles in free space, only provides a lower energy bound.

[1] S. Braun, J. P. Ronzheimer, M. Schreiber, S. S. Hodgman, T. Rom, I. Bloch, and U. Schneider. Negative absolute temperature for motional degrees of freedom. Science, 339(6115):52–55, 2013.